# Running League of Legends on Samsung Chromebook with Ubuntu 12.04.4 ARM

Tags: wine, arm

I purchased this Samsung chromebook and installed xfce along with ubuntu 12.04.4. I am completely new to everything linux, and I realize that using "playonlinux" league of legends is able to be played on most linux machines, but since i am unable to install wine on this ARM chromebook, I am wondering if there is anyway i can play my favorite online game on my new netbook.

Comment: FWIW, there are non-arm Chromebooks. But ARM is very limited, it deosn't run most programs.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

If you have a program compiled for x86 you'll need an emulator to run it on ARM. In its current development state Wine has no such (working) emulator, therefore you can't do what you want.

---

[About wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/):

> Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a
>   compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several
>   POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD.
>   Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or
>   emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls
>   on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other
>   methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications
>   into your desktop.

[About emulation](http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths#head-a97295d7364a2a87f5769eeff9b5105b61b85761):

> When users think of emulators, they think of programs like Dosbox or
>   zsnes. These applications run as virtual machines and are slow, having
>   to emulate each processor instruction. Wine does not do any CPU
>   emulation - hence the name "Wine Is Not an Emulator."

[Wine on non x86 processors](http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths#head-335408c266d3ad8b44816fc794a847305a78b78f):

> Well, it is true that Wine only runs on x86 processors. Unfortunately
>   it will also require quite a lot of work before it runs on other
>   processor architectures.
>
> ...
>
> Then there's what everyone has been waiting for: 'I want to be able to
>   run my x86 Windows applications on any processor architecture I like.'
>   That's the most complex one. Again the prerequisite is that Winelib
>   works on this architecture, which will definitely happen someday. Then
>   'all that is needed' is to integrate an x86 emulator with Wine (and
>   also change Wine's name :-). Ulrich Weigand just did that as an
>   experiment some time ago when he had 'some spare time'. He even
>   managed to get some Win16 applications to run. His code was not in a
>   state where it could be integrated into Wine yet and I don't know how
>   much work has been put into pursuing it. His attempt did spark many
>   discussions on Wine's mailing list though. The result is that we would
>   need a sophisticated emulator including a JIT in order to get
>   something really viable (i.e. not too slow). And developing such an
>   emulator is a whole project in itself.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer - Wine and ARM don't get along.