# Unmet dependencies on a Chromebook

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

I’ve just got Ubuntu 14.04. I changed from Google Chrome (I have a Chromebook) and I’m finding it hard installing NFS world.
It says I have unmet dependencies and so forth.
I tried getting Wine but that was unsuccessful as well...

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to update and upgrade when I updated it this is what appeared:

(it runs a few stuff in between)

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Why is it saying that when I just ran the update?

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I need some help. I only changed to this so I could play NFS world.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/164587/how-can-you-unhold-remove-a-hold-on-a-package

Comment: i tried one of the commands on that page:

Comment: user@chrubuntu:~$ echo wine install|sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: wine
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

Comment: What type of processor are you using? I'm not sure if there is an arm version of wine.

Answer (score 1):

Running apt-get update only fixes the problem after you remove one of the duplicate sources from your "sources.list" file.

To do that, open a terminal and type the following command:

```bsh
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now, look for this line and delete it if it is there:

```bsh
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Next, type this in the terminal:

```bsh
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

There should be only **one** "google-chrome.list" file. If there is more than one file or another file with a similar name, delete it by typing the following command:

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Now that you have eliminated the duplicate source, run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
```

---

To deal with the "wine" issue, you need to enable the "Universe" repository.

Open software-center or synaptic.

Click on "edit" and select "Software Sources".

Make sure "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" is selected.

Click on the "Other Software" tab.

Make sure "Canonical Partners" and "Indipendent" are selected.

You will need to enter a password to apply the changes.

---

The other problem is that the distro you are using, Trusty, is no longer a supported version of Ubuntu and reached EOL January 27, 2014. Consequentially, the URL(s) in your /etc/apt/sources.list file no longer exist.

(**My fix below is not guaranteed to work.** I've pulled it off before. Other times, ended up with broken packages on the system and had to go ahead and re-install. Since you're pretty much already there, it might not hurt to go ahead and give it a try. **Before you do,** I recommend you **first** see this post as this seems to be the accepted answer in the community for dealing with an unsupported or depreciated distro like "raring"  [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

**To fix this, use the following commands.**

First, use:

```bsh
echo 'NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"' | sudo tee /etc/os-release
```

Then, use:

```bsh
echo 'DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"' | sudo tee /etc/lsb-release
```

Next, you can update your /etc/apt/sources.list by using:

```bsh
sudo sed -i 's/raring/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now you can rebuild your package list and upgrade your packages with this command:

```bsh
sudo apt-get clean 
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old 
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You should now be able to install wine.

Finally, don't forget to update the files you may have for any PPA(s) other than google in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory.

Comment: same result after everytg
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @TevinYoungz Also, there is no wine version available for the Samsung ARM chromebook, if that's what you are using, you have to use an emulator to run wine see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/473570/running-league-of-legends-on-samsung-chromebook-with-ubuntu-12-04-4-arm

Comment: im actually using an acer c7. im going to try everything again tho.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. ---should this be a problem this is what shows at the end of when i run an update

Comment: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.---this happened when i tried to repair broken packages

Comment: @TevinYoungz I see the problem, you have an outdated distro (Raring) that is no longer provided by the url(s) in your source list. You need to update to "Trusty" or use the unsupported EOL raring list from the "old" sources list see this post  http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: @TevinYoungz I don't know how you installed but a regular installation from a live disk iso version 14.04 will keep your home directory but will overwrite all your system files to do the upgrade so that you'll be able to keep some of your desktop settings and whatnot. If you are running with chromeOS still though you may need to seek newer documentation on how to install either "trusty (14.04 LTS)", the older "precise (12.04 LTS)", or the new development release "utopic (14.10)" on a chromebook.